# Javascript appending input fields

Tags: javascript

I have this script [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8c4L/) and I am trying to change submitted characters, but when you press for ex: `s` twice as in `ss` instead of showing `xx` it changes it to `ss`

Full code:

```
<body>
    <div id='out'></div>

    <textarea id="in" name="messages" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
```

Js function:

```
    function test(){            
        var origin = document.getElementById("in").value;
        var send = document.getElementById("out"); 

       if(origin =='s'){
        origin = 'z';
       }
        send.innerHTML = origin;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8c4L/1/)

Comment: It seems like your example doesn't correctly match your real goal.  Can you adjust your question to explain what you are really trying to do?  In JS, there are many ways to check strings and modify input or output fields.

Comment: @NickC Thank you, Just think of it this way, for every letter entered in English character, I need to replace them, to another Language, be it Arabic, Chinese, Russia... Now, that is why, I need to detect what key is pressed, and to change that key, with what I have in mind. But, that key needs to be there, after being changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var replacements = {
    "s": "z",
    // repeat for all the characters you want to replace
};

var neworigin = '';
for (var i = 0; i < origin.length; i++) {
    neworigin += (origin[i] in replacements) ? replacements[origin[i]] : origin[i];
    }
}
send.innerHTML = neworigin;
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar, I tried your code, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Silly me, you can't modify strings in Javascript. See new version that constructs a new string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to replace all `s` characters with `z` before assigning to `send`. Your current code only replaces `s` with `z` if `origin` is exactly one `s`. Try this instead:

```
send.innerTHML = origin.replace(/s/g, 'z');
```

That will replace every occurrence of `s` with `z` in `origin` and assign the result to `send.innerHTML`. (In case it isn't obvious, with this you can get rid of the `if` statement.)

If you want to replace all characters with the same substitute character, you can change the regex from `/s/g` to `/./g`. If you want to replace each character with something else that depends on the character, you can use a look-up function:

```
var mapper = function(match) {
    return match === 's' ? 'z' : '?'; // or whatever mapping function you want
}
send.innerHTML = origin.replace(/./g, mapper);
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a simple way of doing this? I am trying to replace all the English characters, plus numbers and more.. so, is this way effective for using a large scale script?

Comment: Do you want to replace them all with the same thing, or different replacements for different characters?

Comment: @kranzdot - If you want to replace all characters with the same thing, you can change the regex from `/s/g` to `/./g`. See my updated answer.